# How can I alter the parameters in my algorithms for better performance?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I ran Multinomial and Bernoulli Naive Bayes, and Linear SVC on a set tweets I have.  They do well on a 60/40 split of 1000 training tweets (80%,80%,90% respectively).

Each algorithm has parameters that can be changed, and I am wondering if I can obtain better results by altering the parameters.  I don't know too much about machine learning beyond training, testing, and predicting, so I was wondering if someone could give me some advice on which parameters I could tweak.

Here is the code I used:

```
import codecs
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB,BernoulliNB
from sklearn import svm

trainfile = 'training_words.txt'
testfile = 'testing_words.txt'

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')  
trainset = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(codecs.open(trainfile,'r','utf8'))
tags = training_labels

mnb = svm.LinearSVC() #Or any other classifier
mnb.fit(trainset, tags)
codecs.open(testfile,'r','utf8')
testset = word_vectorizer.transform(codecs.open(testfile,'r','utf8'))
results = mnb.predict(testset)

print results
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Grid Search Cross Validation` to tune your model parameters with a stratified K-Fold cross-validation split. Here is an example code.

```
import codecs
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB,BernoulliNB
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

testfile = 'testing_words.txt'

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')  
trainset = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(codecs.open(trainfile,'r','utf8'))
tags = training_labels


mnb = svm.LinearSVC() # or any other classifier
# check out the sklearn online docs to see what params choice we have for your
# particular choice of estimator, for SVM, C, class_weight are important ones to tune 
params_space = {'C': np.logspace(-5, 0, 10), 'class_weight':[None, 'auto']}
# build a grid search cv, n_jobs=-1 to use all your processor cores
gscv = GridSearchCV(mnb, params_space, cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
# fit the model
gscv.fit(trainset, tags)
# give a look at your best params combination and best score you have
gscv.best_estimator_
gscv.best_params_
gscv.best_score_


codecs.open(testfile,'r','utf8')
testset = word_vectorizer.transform(codecs.open(testfile,'r','utf8'))
results = gscv.predict(testset)

print results
```

Comment: This gives me an error that "This LinearSVC instance is not fittedyet"

Comment: @user3600497 Which line raises this error? Also, is it possible for you to upload your `testing.words.txt` file via a dropbox share link?

Comment: The line `results = mnb.predict(testset)
`  is causing something to go wrong.  I could definitely upload the testing word set if need be.

Comment: @user3600497 I see what might go wrong. You don't need `mnb` to do the prediction. Instead, you should use `gscv.predict(testset)` because the best estimator (the one survives through cross-validation) is stored inside `gscv` rather than `mnb`.